# How to test a theme during development?

Tags: prestashop

I started to learn how to develop my own theme for Prestashop.

I set a shop on my local server with my theme inside the `themes` folder. When I change the CSS, I can immediately see the changes in my shop. But it seems that when I change the structure (changing `.tpl` files), I need to reload the theme in the back office.

This is really not a convenient process, how do you organize your work during development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Advanced Parameters -> Performance and enable "Recompile templates if the files have been updated". Disable cache on the same page. You can also set `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `true` in your config/defines.inc.php:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true)
```